# Como ajustar uma div para caber em toda a tela caso não haja conteúdo suficiente para isso

Tags: html, css, materialize

Olá,

Estou usando o freamework Materialize para criar um painel administrativo para um sistema que estou criando em PHP, mas sei muito pouco de front-end. Gostaria de ajuda para ajustar a leftbar para caber em toda a tela caso não haja conteúdo suficiente para isso.

Eu tentei aplicar position fixed ou absolute no CSS e de certa forma funciona, mas tem alguns problemas como: a pagecontent passa a ignorar a leftbar e é sobreposta e também em caso de a tela ser pequena, a leftbar não exibe a barra de scroll. Sei que estou fazendo da maneira errada e por isso gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

Coloquei o código do projeto no JSFiddle pra facilitar: https://jsfiddle.net/88ctckn2/5/

@Edit

Vou explicar novamente, acho que não fui claro o suficiente anteriormente.

Se vocês compararem a imagem abaixo com o projeto no JSFiddle, vão ver que é bem semelhante. A diferença é que o leftbar não ocupa todo o espaço na tela em termos de altura (height). Ele só ocupa o tamanho que seu conteúdo lhe permite ocupar. Se você adiciona mais conteúdo, ele fica maior. Eu queria que ele ficasse como na imagem abaixo, do ínicio até o fim da tela.

Acho que ainda não estou sendo claro o suficiente, mas é só comparar o projeto no JSFiddle e a imagem abaixo e verá as diferenças. Eu quero que fique como na imagem abaixo.

https://jsfiddle.net/88ctckn2/5/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Comment: Clay, eu entendi pouco da sua dúvida e quando abri o fiddle entendi menos ainda.. Tente simular uma imagem do problema e de como você quer que fique porque do jeito que ta ai acho difícil aparecer alguma resposta.

Comment: @Bsalvo atualizei a pergunta e adicionei uma imagem de como quero que fique. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode setar a altura minima para a sua left bar, usando o atributo `min-height` na classe `.left`. Para evitar a sobrescrita dessa propriedade (pelo mterialize) use o `!important`.

Exemplo usando o codigo postado (arquivo css):

```
.leftbar {
    background-color: #263238;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    min-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

Produz como resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando uma estrutura vide a referência abaixo, vai funcionar...

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
  float: left;
}

.content {
  width: 75%;
}

.topbar {
  background: black;
  color: #fff
}

.main {
  background: red;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>Esta Barra Vai ocupar a tela toda e mais um pouco</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="topbar">
      topbar
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      main content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tentei aplicar isso ao meu código e não funcionou. Acho que o fato de eu estar usando um framework que já possui várias regras CSS dificulta isso. Se puder tentar aplicar ao meu projeto, eu ficaria muito grato. https://jsfiddle.net/88ctckn2/5/